# jquery $.ajax to php problem

Tags: php, ajax, post, jquery

i have two problems with jquery $.ajax.
first problem is ihave a php file named action.php and here the code:

```
if($_GET['action']=='add'){
    //rest of the code here
}
```

And i use jquery $.Ajax function to call that when form fills:

```
$.ajax({type:"POST", url:"action.php?action=add", data:$("#form").serialize(), cache:false, timeout:10000});
```

this works but i wanted to know is there anyway to send the action=add code with data and not the url?

and the second problem that i have is that i have a link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="delete(4);">delete row from mysql where id is 4</a>
```

and a jquery function:

```
    function deleteUser(id){
    $.ajax({type:"POST", url:"action.php?action=delete", data:"id="+id, cache:false, timeout:10000});}
```

and of course the action.php code:

```
if($_GET['action']=='deletestudent'){
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM `students` WHERE `student_id` = {$_POST['id']}");
}
```

but it doesn't work.what should i do?

Answer (score 3):

**First part:** Yes

```
var postData = $("#form").serialize();
postData.action = 'add';
$.ajax({
    type:"POST"
  , url: "action.php"
  , data: postData
  , cache: false
  , timeout:10000
});
```

**For the 2nd part:** that isn't working because your "action" values are not congruent: `delete` vs `deletestudent`.  Nor are your function names: `delete()` vs `deleteUser()`

Also, I'd recommend applying some SQL injection protection in that query as well.

Comment: ew. whats up with your commas? thats gross.

Comment: Gross?  I don't like postfixed separators.  Seeing them at the start of the line makes it abundantly clear that I'm dealing with a new value/parameter/whatevever.  Also makes editing easier.

Answer (score 1):

You have a function `deleteUser()` and you are using `delete()` even you're sending post action is `delete` while you're php script is looking for `deletestudent`

make your onclick `onclick="deleteUser(4);"`

and change your action from

```
$.ajax({url:"action.php?action=delete&id="+id, cache:false, timeout:10000});}
```

to

```
$.ajax({url:"action.php?action=deletestudent&id="+id, cache:false, timeout:10000});}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem:

You can add to your form a hidden input with the name/value you need. Example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="add" />
```

For the second problem:

According to your code, it seems that you are send "delete" but in the condition you are testing if equal to "deletestudent", maybe that's your problem.

Answer (score -1):

chnage the type to GET o remove it, $.ajax default type is GET

```
$.ajax({url:"action.php?action=delete&id="+id, cache:false, timeout:10000});}
```

in php change your

```
....WHERE `student_id` = {$_GET['id']}");
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I *had* to vote this down.  GET requests should be idempotent, **period**. http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/whenToUseGet.html